# Visual Editor not working properly

Tags: tinymce, syntax-highlighting, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

I have facing this issue since last one month. I would like to display my source code using the Syntax Highlighter so i have changed my editor mode from visual to text. I put my code in

```
 [html]
   <div class="panel panel-default panel-faq">
     <div class="panel-heading">
       <a data-toggle="collapse">
           <h4 class="panel-title">
                 Questions                                
            </h4>
       </a>
     </div>  
   </div>  
 [/html]
```

Then i switched to visual mode then the editor is give a new line space between the html code. like bellow.

```
    [html]

<div class="panel panel-default panel-faq">

<div class="panel-heading">
           <a data-toggle="collapse">

<h4 class="panel-title">
                     Questions                                
                </h4>

           </a>
         </div>


       </div>


     [/html]
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You add the shortcode (and all shortcodes) in visual mode, not in text mode.